# How to solve time out in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, execution-time

I want import huge (**at least** 300 mb) sql scripts via phpMyAdmin.

I've tried:

```
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 540
memory_limit = 1000M
```

in my `php.ini` file, but I'm **still** getting timeout errors during importing.

Comment: your script is taking more than 300 sec to execute so time out..try to increase it more...FYI u should look at your code first why script is taking too much time to run

Comment: What error are you getting *exactly*?

Comment: max_execution_time = 550 is it right?

Comment: I got errors are "Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit same file and import will resume."

Comment: Then why not resubmit the same file? phpMyAdmin seems smart enough to handle the problem?

Comment: oh, will I resubmit the same file?

Comment: Ok thank to all it work well....

Comment: why don't you use hedisql instead of phpmysql. save bandwithd and time.

Comment: A 300Mb SQL file ? Ain't SQL text-based ?

Answer (score 156):

If even after repeated upload you still get timeout error, pleasechange your settings in

`\phpmyadmin\libraries\config.default.php`

from `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300;` to `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;` and restart. Now there is no execution time limit (trust we are talking about local server).

Source : [Change Script time out in phpmyadmin](http://situsnya.wordpress.com/2008/09/11/change-script-timeout-in-phpmyadmin/)

Comment: Or better still, put that setting in your `phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, @canaaerus, but it messed my system even after I changed its place and finally undone it and restarted apache2 server. Now it says Error

SQL query: DocumentationEdit Edit

SELECT `comment`
FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__column_info`
WHERE db_name = 'bot4a'
AND table_name = ''
AND column_name = '(db_comment)'

MySQL said: Documentation
#1100 - Table 'pma__column_info' was not locked with LOCK TABLES

Comment: @Rodrigo: I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with the above setting. Also you should ask this a new question and not as a comment.

Comment: `config.inc.php` is at `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/phpMyAdmin` with MAMP on Mac OS X

Comment: As @chuchunaku says -  YOU SHOULD EDIT config.inc.php INSTEAD or it won't work. This is the settings it reverts to not active configuration.

Comment: Thanks, this also solved mine I stuck in this for about 4 hours.

Comment: Another source : https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/apache-and-php-limits-and-timeouts

Comment: If your visiting from 2018 on, I found this file in, /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/ on my Mac. Just edit config.inc.php and thats it.

Comment: I am using AWS server, How can I solved this issue on AWS?

Answer (score 18):

I'm using version 4.0.3 of MAMP along with phpmyadmin. The top of /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/libraries/config.default.php reads:

> DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, EDIT config.inc.php INSTEAD !!!

Changing the following line in /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php and restarting MAMP worked for me.

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
```

Comment: Some of the other answers are saying to edit a file that says "DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE" why are people ignoring the notice? This answer gives solid advice and doesn't ignore the notice at the top of the file.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue and I used command line in order to import the SQL file. This method has 3 advantages:

1. It is a very easy way by running only 1 command line
2. It runs way faster
3. It does not have limitation

If you want to do this just follow this 3 steps:

1. Navigate to this path (i use wamp):

   C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin>
2. Copy your sql file inside this path (ex file.sql)
3. Run this command:

   mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql

<sup>Note: if you already have your msql enviroment variable path set, you don't need to move your file.sql in the bin directory and you should only navigate to the path of the file.</sup>

Comment: For others on osx; you might have to use `./mysql` (instead of just `mysql`)

Answer (score 12):

But if you are using Plesk, change your settings in :

`/usr/local/psa/admin/htdocs/domains/databases/phpMyAdmin/libraries/config.default.php`

Change `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300;` to `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;`

And restart with Plesk UI or use:

`/etc/init.d/psa restart`
 and
`/etc/init.d/httpd restart`

Answer (score 9):

If using Cpanel/WHM the location of file `config.default.php` is under

`/usr/local/cpanel/base/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin/libraries`

and you should change the `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300;` to `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;`

Answer (score 5):

If any of you happen to use WAMP then at least in the current version (3.0.6 x64) there's a file located in `<your-wamp-dir>\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` which overrides some of your php.ini options.

**Edit this part:**

`# To import big file you can increase values
 php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 512M
 php_admin_value post_max_size 512M
 php_admin_value max_execution_time 600
 php_admin_value max_input_time 600`

Comment: THANK YOU for posting this -- really helped me out!

Comment: This really works. file \alias\phpmyadmin.conf overrides conf.inc.php file, which is located in app\phpmyadmin directory

Answer (score 4):

I was having the issue previously in `XAMPP` localhost with phpmyadmin version 4.2.11.

Increasing the timeout in `php.ini` didn't helped either.

Then I edited `xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.default.php` to change the value of `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit']`, which was 300 by default.

That solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above answers solved it for me.

I cant even find the 'libraries' folder in my xampp - ubuntu also.

So, I simply restarted using the following commands:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

- Just restarted apache and mysql. Logged in phpmyadmin again and it worked as usual.

Thanks me..!!

Comment: I guess restart or reload the service are just a normal step when editing configuration file. If phpmyadmin was in timeout, there was cleary another problem that should be troobleshoot before restart all web server directly

Answer (score 1):

go to  /phpMyAdmin/libraries/config.default.php

Line Number 719

Change

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300;
```

to

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
```

Comment: This is not a good idea to set it to zero, better to increase the limit as needed without removing the limit

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too and tried different memory expansion techniques I found on the web but had more troubles with it.
I resolved to using the MySQL console `source` command, and of course you don't have to worry about phpMyAdmin or PHP maximum execution time and limits.

Syntax: `source c:\path\to\dump_file.sql`

Note: It's better to specify an absolute path to the dump file since the mysql working directory might not be known.

Answer (score -2):

To increase the phpMyAdmin Session Timeout, open config.inc.php in the root phpMyAdmin directory and add this setting (anywhere).

```
$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = <your_new_timeout>;
```

Where  is some number larger than 1800.

Note:

Always keep on mind that a short cookie lifetime is all well and good for the development server. So do not do this on your production server.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886740/how-to-set-my-phpmyadmin-to-not-time-out-so-quickly)