# How to set my phpmyadmin user session to not time out so quickly?

Tags: phpmyadmin, timeout, settings

I work on my wamp for localhost backend development everyday.

I feel annoyed by phpmyadmin auto log out out quickly.  Is there any way I could get rid of this or extend the timeout?

Where can I set this timeout value?

Answer (score 296, accepted):

To increase the `phpMyAdmin` **Session Timeout**, open `config.inc.php` in the root `phpMyAdmin` directory and add this setting (anywhere).

```
$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = <your_new_timeout>;
```

Where `<your_new_timeout>` is some number larger than 1800.

**Note**:

Always keep on mind that a short cookie lifetime is all well and good for the development server. So do not do this on your production server.

Comment: The UI says that user settings (such as the session timeout) will only be saved for the current session unless the permanent phpMyAdmin configuration storage is properly configured (which is probably not the case for a default WAMP installation). If this is true, setting the timeout in the config.inc.php might be better.

Comment: In ubuntu, `config.inc.php` is accessed fast and easy by `sudo gedit /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`

Comment: I found that I also needed to add the following line to the config.inc.php file: ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', <your_new_timeout>);  And, I'm pretty sure the two values need to be equivalent.  BTW: [on my distro, at least] the config.inc.php file is in /etc/phpmyadmin/.

Comment: whatever you do, don't set it to 0 thinking that means never, it will actually instantly log you out once you log in....

Comment: An anonymous user suggests: "just comment the //$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie'; in your config.ini file"

Comment: @dangel If you used the UI to set your timeout preference, any configuration you have in **config.inc.php** seems to be overridden. So, if you do happen to lock yourself out by setting timeout to 1, you can comment out `$cfg [‘Servers’][$i][‘auth_type’] = 'cookie';` and replace it with `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';`

Comment: make sure to modify session.gc_maxlifetime also otherwise you'll get a " Your PHP parameter session.gc_maxlifetime is lower than cookie validity configured in phpMyAdmin, because of this, your login will expire sooner than configured in phpMyAdmin."

Comment: @subedi-kishor another thing to mention is `session.gc_maxlifetime`, which has to be the same as `LoginCookieValidity`, otherwise the smaller value will be the actual value.

Comment: This answer is not working for me as of December 2018, might be deprecated

Comment: There are two files. `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/config.inc.php` 
 and `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/test/test_data/config.inc.php`  In the first file, I see no `$cfg` variable already declared. How does this solution work? In the test version of the file (2nd file), I do see the `$cfg` variable. Is test really the correct place to configure production phpmyadmin?

Comment: Every config in the test file is in this format 
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';`. Should we instead of `$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = <your_new_timeout>;` be typing in 
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['LoginCookieValidity'] = 12345;`?

`

Comment: I'm sure that's the case, ahn, but anyway, note that the answer says to **add** the cfg option. It does not already exist... for some reason.

Comment: How do you find config.inc.php? my etc/phpmyadmin folder is empty. On ec2

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04 the file is `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/config.default.php`

Comment: @AhmedIsmail Right at the beginning of `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/config.default.php` there is a big warning saying `DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, EDIT config.inc.php INSTEAD !!!`

Comment: Please keep in mind the newer versions of xampp bitnami, this param is already set there with a value of 1440, just you need to update and add your own timeout there!

Comment: You can and should set `session.gc_maxlifetime` in the config too. Probably best to add something like: `ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $cfg['LoginCookieValidity']);`

Answer (score 262):

Once you're logged into phpmyadmin look on the top navigation for "Settings" and click that then:

"Features" >

[image: ...and you'll find "Login cookie validity" which is typically set to 1440.]

Unfortunately changing it through the UI means that the changes don't persist between logins.

Comment: I sometimes wonder why they still bother making user interfaces, it seems like everyone still uses the command line and `ini` files for configuring their work environment...

Comment: Way easier solution, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This only works if you keep logging in -- as noted above, modifications to config.inc.php will persist between logins.

Comment: On Ubuntu I need to change my global php.ini (/etc/apache2/php.ini) `session.gc_maxlifetime` value, because otherwise phpmyadmin can't use own settings. I think this apply to any OS.

Comment: Note that you can't set a value greater than 9223372036854775806 or it will result in a integer overflow.

Comment: @LittleFinger - I'm sure you're correct, but that's hilarious. I'll give you a dollar if phpMyAdmin is still around in 300 million years and your login is still active. :)

Comment: `Server:localhost -> Settings -> Features -> General -> Login cookie validity`

Comment: @squarecandy come on be generous to LittleFinger. Put the dollar in a savings account, and given today's typical interest rates, in 300 million years, it could be worth... 2 dollars!

Comment: This is the correct answer; does not require any file configuration.

Comment: On WampServer this option gets reset as soon as it restarts. Need to actually change the PHPMyAdmin config file for it to stick.

Comment: must be the accepted answer

Comment: According to PHPMyAdmin changing this in the UI "will be saved for current session only." It's better to alter the `config.inc.php` as the other answer suggests.

Comment: how can I activate this setting? It is not available on the UI of the phpmyadmin 4.8.4.

Comment: This feature no longer available in the GUI (verified as of phpMyAdmin 5.x)
You'll need to do 2 things, add the line to config.inc.php i.e. $cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 3000;
Then update your php.ini and make sure that value is >=
session.gc_maxlifetime = 3000
then restart httpd and reload page