# phpMyAdmin, Session Time-Out / Re-Logging In

Tags: phpmyadmin, session-timeout

In phpMyAdmin, when my session has timed out, and I click a link anywhere on the page, an alert message pops up and says I need to log in again.  It then takes me to the main login page, which I have to log in again, and then returns to me to the page I started from (not the link I clicked).

Instead, I would like to see an actual login box on this alert page, to save the cumbersome step of redirecting to the main login page, as well as, after successfully logging in, bringing the user to the link they clicked on (not the link they were at).  This would save a lot of time for us heavy users!

I'm not sure if this is the correct may to make a feature request of this sort, so please direct me to the proper place to submit this feature request.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a reasonable thing to expect; the best place to suggest it is at the feature request tracker: http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/feature-requests/

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In `config.inc.php` file in `phpMyAdmin` folder

Change `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']`  value to `'cookie'`

To increase the phpMyAdmin Session Timeout, open config.inc.php in the root phpMyAdmin directory and add this setting (anywhere).

```
$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = <your_new_timeout>;
```

Where  is some number larger than 1800.

Note:

Always keep on mind that a short cookie lifetime is all well and good for the development server. So do not do this on your production server.

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886740/how-to-set-my-phpmyadmin-to-not-time-out-so-quickly)