# phpMyadmin does not show when query completes

Tags: phpmyadmin

If I execute a query using phpMyAdmin in a browser, AND the execution is quick (e.g., a few minutes or less), everything is fine.  But when I execute queries that take 15 to 30 minutes or more, the yellow "loading" flag never goes away, and phpMyAdmin never refreshes the browser window to tell me when the query is done.  Eventually, I have to use other means (e.g., check a table to see if the updates are there) to see if the query completed.  In all cases (so far), the queries do execute correctly.  But it is frustrating not to know when it completes. Incidentally, these are queries that update tables, so I am not looking for a display of results, merely a display that says the process completed.

I am using phpMyAdmin 4.4.13.1, on a remote host at InMotionHosting.

Answer (score 0):

Your phpMyAdmin possibly times out. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18886833/2240141) to change session timeout and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21641325/2240141) to change execution timeout.

It's all out there, try to just look a bit around.