# Why phpmyadmin doesn't notice me that it reaches the maxmium php execution time?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm using phpmyadmin to export one of my database.
And it was huge ( larger than 1 GiB )
And export procedure ended because of the PHP had run 360 seconds ( maxmium execution time ) and was killed while I thought that the backup file was correct and complete.

Later, I want a rollback.
I drop the old database.
And I import the backup sql file.

And

**My data are partially lost.**

Why phpmyadmin doesn't notice me???
I'm really ******* angry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve time out in phpmyadmin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707532/how-to-solve-time-out-in-phpmyadmin)

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: when uploading there do is an out of time error, but downloading has not.

Answer (score 0):

For databases huge like that phpMyAdmin is not the best solution. Better use shell command to dump/import database. Under linux (most likely you are on linux)

```
mysqldump -u username -p database_name > dump_file_name.sql
```

Copy it, i.e. with FTP to other server and then import like:

```
mysql -u username -p  database_name < dump_file_name.sql
```

After "-p" you can immediately put your password, but you can also skip it and you'll be asked to enter it.

Comment: I know that. I swear I'll not use phpMyAdmin to backup huge databased any more.    At least it should tell me that procedure is not finished!