# Error time out when import file sql into phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm using Mac Yosmite. When I import file sql (3MB) into phpmyadmin, I get this error:

> Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit
>   same file and import will resume.

I already edited file php.ini, but it is still not working.

My config: php.ini

```
post_max_size = 256M
upload_max_filesize = 256M
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 600
memory_limit = 512M
```

And ~/Sites/phpmyadmin/libraries/config.default.php, change from

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300;` to `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate what changes you made to php.ini, or better yet, include a copy, preferably trimmed of any non-essential bits, like most of the comments. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Answer (score -1):

SEE this

[How to solve time out in phpmyadmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707532/how-to-solve-time-out-in-phpmyadmin)

You can use other tools to connect MySql,for example MySql query browser or MySql Administrator tools in witch you can sett server  ip (or domain) and MySql Port (3306) and username and password,
then use restore database ...