# 1000mb database file is not uploading completely

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

We have a Magento site.

We have a large database of 1000MB for that site.

When we try to import database through phpmyadmin, it's not uploading the full database. Lot of tables are missing after uploading.

Qe are getting this error :

> Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit
>   same file and import will resume

We have a GoDaddy cpanel and phpmyadmin.

Is there any way to upload a large database completely?

I am planning to change php.ini settings as mentioned in this question:

[How to solve time out in phpmyadmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707532/how-to-solve-time-out-in-phpmyadmin)

But I could not able to find php.ini file.

Have I need to edit the default Magento phi.ini.sample?

Comment: Tell us something more about your host. Its a shared hosting, its a VPS or a dedicated server? Do you have root access?

Comment: godaddy its a shared hosting, we have a ssh access.

Comment: Why don't you compress the file - .sql files can be nicely compressed in most of the cases.

Comment: we tried that, now its 98mb, still not uploading, so we planning to chnage settings size in php.ini file

Comment: For databases that large,  I think it is best to use mysqldump to dump SQL file and mysql command-line interface to import the SQL.

Comment: okay, we will try commands by putty software.

Comment: is there any way in phpmyadmin or through ssh, we can change the old domain name to new domain name in all places in database file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try like this in your Godaddy SSH,

1. Log on to your server.
2. At the command line, type su -. This gives you root access.
3. At the command line, type mysql -uroot -p
4. Enter your MySQL root password.
5. Select yourdatabase name for insert data by writing this command, USE YOURDATABASENAME
6. Then load source sql file as SOURCE D:\profile20\database.sql
7. Press enter for insert data.

[This video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TLlwX8D_y1U) may help you.

Comment: "godaddy its a shared hosting, we have a ssh access" asked before

Comment: is there any way in phpmyadmin or through ssh, we can change the old domain name to new domain name in all places in database file

Comment: you mean you are looking something like this ?https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkEewzaIzbU

Comment: i used this : mysql -uUSERNAME -p DATABASE < path/to/dump.sql its works fine.

Answer (score 0):

use sqlsplitter, It will created small chunk of you large sql file and then upload all these small files

Comment: Yes, you have to download it. It is very light weigh but effective.  check this link. http://www.rusiczki.net/2007/01/24/sql-dump-file-splitter/

Comment: is there any way in phpmyadmin or through ssh, we can change the old domain name to new domain name in all places in database file

Comment: yes, there are plenty of script that search in the database and change the domain name in database.

Comment: Check this url 
https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/
It will definitely help you.

Comment: thanks a lot, we will try this.

is there any ssh commands that can replace the old doamin name to new domain name?

Comment: I don't have any idea about that command, I generally use this script for the changes.

Comment: How do you even upload multiple files within phpMyAdmin ?