# Script timeout passed, resubmit same file and import will resume error in phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to upload some big data onto phpmyadmin

I am getting this error where it does partial uploads

```
Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit same file and import will resume.
```

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707532/how-to-solve-time-out-in-phpmyadmin) link where it says change the config on `\phpmyadmin\libraries\config.default.php`

I cannot see this directory in the phpmyadmin. OS Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Go to xampp/phpMyAdmin/libraries/config.default.php 
find `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300;` line no 695 and replace `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

i think there were problems with your sql codes, try to surrounding your sql codes (edit with text editor eg. notepad++) with following statement :

```
SET autocommit=0;
SET unique_checks=0;
SET foreign_key_checks=0;
```

at the beginning, and

```
COMMIT;
SET unique_checks=1;
SET foreign_key_checks=1;
```

at the end.

and you could import your sql file once again.
give it a try.