# MYSQL multiple select from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have X tables and I want a single query to get all data which I want. The reason I want this method is I have more than 10.000 records in my database, so I must use only 1 query, because if I use 3-4 query and ten gether the data, it would take really long time to be executed by the server.

So the tables:

```
** book_info **    
bookId   status        title
------   ------        -----
101      available     How to cook
102      available     IT tips and tricks
103      unavailable   How to use your calc
etc...


** book_writers **    
bookId   writer
------   ------
101      Tom
102      Mike
103      Mike
etc...


** book_log **    
bookId   action   client   date
------   ------   ------   ----
103      loan     Fred     2017-6-10
102      loan     Anna     2017-6-8
101      return   Anita    2017-5-3
101      loan     Anita    2017-2-2
etc...
```

And what I want in only one query:

```
bookId   status      title                writer   lastLoan   lastReturn
------   ------      -----                ------   --------   ----------
101      available   How to cook          Tom      2017-2-2   2017-5-3
102      available   IT tips and tricks   Mike     2017-6-8   -
etc...
```

I tried it by using JOIN and UNION, but I could not do it.

---

**UPDATE**

So since I got good solutions from you guys, I finally built the query that I have looked for. But one thing that I can not do is using "parent" query variable in "child" join query.

So I am having a table which contains the content of the books:

```
** book_content **    
bookId   content
------   -------
101      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...
102      Donec ut lacus non odio blandit molestie
103      Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum...
etc...
```

I tried to query it like

```
select
  bi.bookId
  bd.content
from
  books_info as bi
left outer join
(
  select
    bookId
    content
  from
    book_content
  where
    bookId = bi.bookId
) bd on bi.bookId = bd.bookId
```

But the SQL says `#1054 - Unknown column 'bi.bookId' in 'where clause'` in the join select. How can I use `bi.bookId` in child join query?

Comment: Please show your attempted query.

Comment: It was just a few tries in PHPMyadmin.

Comment: looks like simple query with a few joins, a group_concat for writers, and a subselect for loan/return to me.

Comment: i have posted query, check the query i have exected it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  inner and left join  using two time book_log

```
select i.bookId, i.status, i.title, w.writer, max(l1.date) lastLoan,  max(l2.date) lastReturn
from book_info as i
inner join book_writers w on i.bookId = w.bookId
inner join book_log l1 on i.book_id = l1.book_id and l1.action ='load'
left join  book_log l2 on i.book_id = l2.book_id and l2.action ='return'
group by i.bookId, i.status, i.title
```

and (as suggested  by Tuncay in the comment below)

use a group_concat if have more then one authot

```
select i.bookId, i.status, i.title, group_concat(w.writer), max(l1.date) lastLoan,  max(l2.date) lastReturn
from book_info as i
inner join book_writers w on i.bookId = w.bookId
inner join book_log l1 on i.book_id = l1.book_id and l1.action ='load'
left join  book_log l2 on i.book_id = l2.book_id and l2.action ='return'
group by i.bookId, i.status, i.title
```

Comment: I'd suggest a group concat on writers (books might have more than one author, ie bookId in that table might not be unique). Also joining book_log twice might not necessarily return loan and return from same (last) row, so I'd suggest a subquery on join for that.

Comment: Can you please write it?

Comment: .. answer  uodated with group concat too  and add the missing group by

Comment: Thank you! Anyways it says "action" is ambigous.

Comment: Is it typo "t1" rather than "l1"?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried it but it says I have to user "SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1;". I put it at the beggining of the code but now it timeouts. :(

Comment: check for timeout duration and eventually increase it

Answer (score 0):

try this query hope it will work.

```
SELECT bi.bookId,status,title,writer,bl.lastLoan,
           bl.lastReturn,bl.totalLoan,bl.totalReturn
from book_info bi
left outer join book_writers as bw on bi.bookId = bw.bookId
left outer join(
SELECT 
bookId,
COUNT(CASE WHEN action = 'loan' THEN action END) AS totalLoan,
COUNT(CASE WHEN action = 'return' THEN action END) AS totalReturn,
 CASE
        WHEN action = 'loan' THEN date
END AS lastLoan,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN action = 'return' THEN date
END) AS lastReturn

FROM book_log
group by bookId

)  bl on bi.bookId = bl.bookId
group by bi.bookId
```

If you have book content it will display otherwise it will display null.

```
select
  bi.bookId
  bd.content
from
  books_info as bi
left join book_content as bd on bi.bookId = bd.bookId
group by bi.bookId
```

[image]

**EDIT :** Added 2nd Query for Book Content.

Comment: added totalLoans, totalReturn. Make sure it's perfoming more operation in single query so it will be lengthy and time consuming.

Comment: I am still testing. What is the "THEN date END" method?

Comment: THEN an END is keyword and "date" is your column name to display date

Comment: I see. I tested it yesterday a lot, and it seems it works, huge thanks for you and everyone! But one more thing, I update the post.

Comment: Yep this is what I tried but it seems my MySQL getting timeout everytime. Stuck in "Loading" page and I must restart it. Anyways I am working with ~300.000 records.

Comment: I am using PHPMyadmin. I navigate to SQL and paste my code and click Go. And it showing the yellow text "Loading" and stucks there.

Comment: Ref this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21641325/5541139, is it same ?

Comment: I tested the code out with ~30 records and it works. So the execution time is too much. Since its not my own server, i can not change any settings.

Comment: But can you please show me how can i use parent query variable in child join select?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take at it. Basically the same as scaisEdge, but a bit more detailed. I created an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7391ca/8) for it.

```
select
  i.`bookId`,
  i.`status`,
  i.`title`,
  group_concat(w.`writer`) as writers,
  coalesce(max(ll.`date`), '') as lastLoan,
  coalesce(max(lr.`date`), '') as lastReturn
from
  book_info i
left join
  book_writers w on w.bookId=i.bookId
left join
  book_log ll on (ll.bookId=i.bookId) and (ll.`action`='loan')
left join
  book_log lr on (lr.bookId=i.bookId) and (lr.`action`='return') and (lr.`date` >= ll.`date`)
group by
  w.bookId
```

Comment: It works well, but can you please add another field like "totalLoans" which counts how many loans has the books? I updated the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6aca38/3
And it has also duplicated columns at the "owners" if I add more records in logs